# Find the combination of numbers that closest matches a target number

Tags: c#, list

I have a List `List<MyClass>`, `MyClass` contains an integer value `cost`.

Given a target number, how can I determine a combination of elements so that their total cost is as close to the target as possible without exceeding it.

Comment: how do you define the `combination of elements` sum of two or sum of `n`

Comment: I suspect you're going to have a hard time with this, since it's the canonical example of a [P versus NP Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). Really your only hope is to brute force it.

Comment: Strange how this reads so much like a copy/paste of a homework assignment... Which class?

Comment: are you expecting this (I am not clear about the question tho)? `(your list with the sum).Where(x => x.cost < target).Max(x => x.cost)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), where weights and values are the same. If your target is not too big, the classical solution based on dynamic programming, with complexity O(n * t) (n is the number of values and t is the target), should be fine.
It shouldn't be hard to find online an implementation in any language.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Func<IEnumerable<MyClass>, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<MyClass>>> getAllSubsets = null;
getAllSubsets = xs =>
    (xs == null || !xs.Any())
        ? Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<MyClass>>()
        :  xs.Skip(1).Any()
            ? getAllSubsets(xs.Skip(1))
                .SelectMany(ys => new [] { ys, xs.Take(1).Concat(ys) })
            : new [] { Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>(), xs.Take(1) };

Random rnd = new Random();              
MyClass[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new MyClass() { cost = rnd.Next(5, 100) }).ToArray();

var result =
    getAllSubsets(array)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            MyClass = x,
            TotalCost = x.Sum(y => y.cost),
        })
        .Where(x => x.TotalCost <= 50)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalCost)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

One such run of this code gave me:

[image: result]